# MySQL Ordering Results by the order of Where Clause Matched

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a query that tokenizes a phrase on spaces and needs to look for the best match for the phrase.  It needs to return that match first.  I'm trying to do this in a single query using where clauses.  Is this possible?  I'm trying something along these lines:

for: my phrase

select name from myTable where name="my phrase" or name like "%my phrase%" or (name like "%my%" and name like "%phrase%") or (name like "%my%" or name like "%phrase%") limit 5;

Basically I want the top five matches in order of where clause matched.  I know that by default MySQL evaluates the where clauses in an optimized manner.  Is there any way to force it to evaluate them in order?  And if so, how can I make it return the results in order of where clause matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fulltext search instead of this. It's much faster, more flexible and let you score results. [Google for more](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=mysql+php+fulltext+search&btnG=Szukaj+w+Google&lr=)

```
SELECT ..., MATCH(col_name) AGAINST ('my pharse') AS score FROM tbl_name WHERE MATCH(col_name) AGAINST('my pharse') ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: Beautiful.  That's exactly what I needed, I didn't realize that was what full text search in MySQL did.  Silly me for not digging deeper, thanks!